# lambda syntax, not sure why I am getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called `df_freight` and I would like to create a new column called "LM", based on a condition in another column called "Cost rate". The condition is: if it contains code "lm" right "lm" otherwise "not lm".

```
df_freight =pd.DataFrame(
     {'Cost rate': ['11.53 LM', '12.22kg','22 LM','sdfdfsdf'],
     'TO Number': ['x12', 'x13','x14','x15']})


df_fright["LM"] = df_fright.apply(lambda row: "LM" if row["Cost rate"].str.contans("lm") else "Not lm", axis=1)
```

but I am getting attribute error

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-d277ddb08fc7> in <module>
----> 1 df_fright["LM"] = df_fright.apply(lambda row: "LM" if row["Cost rate"].str.contans("lm") else "Not lm", axis=1)

~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7766             kwds=kwds,
   7767         )
-> 7768         return op.get_result()
   7769 
   7770     def applymap(self, func, na_action: Optional[str] = None) -> DataFrame:

~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    183             return self.apply_raw()
    184 
--> 185         return self.apply_standard()
    186 
    187     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    274 
    275     def apply_standard(self):
--> 276         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    277 
    278         # wrap results

~\Anaconda3\envs\general\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    288             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    289                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 290                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    291                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    292                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

<ipython-input-94-d277ddb08fc7> in <lambda>(row)
----> 1 df_fright["LM"] = df_fright.apply(lambda row: "LM" if row["Cost rate"].str.contans("lm") else "Not lm", axis=1)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

isn't the syntax correct?

Comment: Also, `df_fright` is not defined, but that seems to be just a typo. In the future, please make a [mre].

Comment: You have a typo: `contans("lm")` => missing `i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row["Cost rate"]` is already a string, so you don't have to use `.str`. Also to check if a substring is contained in a string use `in` instead of `contains()`.

```
import pandas as pd

df_freight = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Cost rate': ['11.53 LM', '12.22kg', '22 LM', 'sdfdfsdf'],
     'TO Number': ['x12', 'x13', 'x14', 'x15']})

df_freight["LM"] = df_freight.apply(lambda row: "LM" if "lm" in row["Cost rate"] else "Not lm", axis=1)

print(df_freight)
>   Cost rate TO Number      LM
  0  11.53 LM       x12  Not lm
  1   12.22kg       x13  Not lm
  2     22 LM       x14  Not lm
  3  sdfdfsdf       x15  Not lm
```

Returns False for all because comparing strings is case-sensitive. So you have to add `.lower()` to compare them:

```
import pandas as pd

df_freight = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Cost rate': ['11.53 LM', '12.22kg', '22 LM', 'sdfdfsdf'],
     'TO Number': ['x12', 'x13', 'x14', 'x15']})

df_freight["LM"] = df_freight.apply(lambda row: "LM" if "lm" in row["Cost rate"].lower() else "Not lm", axis=1)

print(df_freight)
>   Cost rate TO Number      LM
  0  11.53 LM       x12      LM
  1   12.22kg       x13  Not lm
  2     22 LM       x14      LM
  3  sdfdfsdf       x15  Not lm
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I needed str since the type was object. Got another error due to type when directly applying ur code, so I changed the type to str and it worked well. thanks for .lower() tip, i didn't think of it and results would have bee not complete without it

Comment: In the example data all values in `df_freight["Cost rate"]` contain a valid string, I assume in reality they could contain something like a number of NaN, especially if they were read from a file before and the type automatically determined. Then `.lower()` would throw an error. So adding `.str` makes sense. For some reason when I try this exact code adding `.str` causes an error, but wrapping it as `str(row["Cost rate"])` does the trick, basically two ways to write the same thing I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a vectorized operation:

```
df_freight["LM"] = np.where(df_freight['Cost rate'].str.contains('lm', case=False),
                            'LM', 'Not lm')
print(df)

# Output
  Cost rate TO Number      LM
0  11.53 LM       x12      LM
1   12.22kg       x13  Not lm
2     22 LM       x14      LM
3  sdfdfsdf       x15  Not lm
```

Comment: thanks for solution, i should push myself to use numpy more often, instead of trying to avoid it

Comment: This is the best solution, but it doesn't directly answer OP's question. Could you add a short explanation? Something like, *"`row["Cost rate"]` is a string, so it doesn't have a `str` attribute. You want to use the whole column: `df_freight['Cost rate'].str`. Then you can use a vectorized operation:"*

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead. This will work also this is easiest one mentioned here. **No need for str**, **no need of axis**, **no need for vectorize**, **no need for anything** simple and easy. ***enjoy!***

```
df_freight['LM'] = df_freight['Cost rate'].apply(lambda x: 'LM' if "LM" in x else "Not lm")
```

Output

```
    Cost rate   TO Number   LM
0   11.53 LM         x12    LM
1   12.22kg          x13    Not lm
2   22 LM            x14    LM
3   sdfdfsdf         x15    Not lm
```